# JSON file data display on HTML using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

Trying to append data from this json file to html doc.
This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Beer.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: processBeer,
    error: function(){ alert("error"); }
  });
  function processBeer(data){
    $(".box").append("Hello");
  }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="box" id='d'>


</div>
```

Comment: The hello part is just to try and get anything to append to the box.  Right now cant get anything to come up.  Using chrome.

Comment: Could you look in the "Network" tab in your chrome debugger to see what the status of the AJAX request is

Comment: Yes, looks like it's probably a syntax error as Explsion Pills points out. Use the console in the debugger to track down your errors.

Comment: Are you using any debuggers?  There are at least two errors I see (brackets, as well as not passing an argument to processBeer) that would be very evident if you were using Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, etc.

Comment: Ok going to try and use the debugger, really new to HTML thanks a lot guys.

I fixed the data passing problem and the brackets though.

Comment: ok getting the errors, I am getting one that says on line one I have an unexpected end of input, line 1: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: The other one seems to be an issue with the script languages I am linking:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: "Could you look in the "Network" tab in your chrome debugger to see what the status of the AJAX request is"

doesnt even come up

Comment: Is you're file all one line?  If so, the unexpected end of input would be due to the lack of closing brackets.  As for the src errors, you need to have the `http://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the script that is probably preventing it from running altogether.  You never close the paren for the `.ready` call